# javascript getting my textbox to display a variable

Tags: javascript, html, textbox

So I have some basic code in html here, i just have two textbox which u can type numbers in and when you click the button, it adds em both up, and in a perfect world, it would display the answer in that third textbox.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function myfunction()
    {
        var first = document.getElementById("textbox1").value;
        var second = document.getElementById("textbox2").value;
        var answer = +first + +second;
        var textbox3 = answer;
    }
</script>
<body>
    <input type="text" name="textbox1" id="textbox1" />
    +
    <input type="text" name="textbox2" id="textbox2" />
    <input type="submit" name="button" id="button1" onclick="myfunction()" value="=" />
    
    <input type="text" name="textbox3" id="textbox3" readonly="true"/>
    <br />
    Your answer is: --
</body>
</html>
```

however, i can't get the answer to display in that textbox3. Does anyone know how to assign a value to that third textbox from a variable?

also, as an added bonus, if anyone knows a way to also make the last line "Your answer is: --" display the answer as well, that would be amazing.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```js
function myfunction() {
  var first = document.getElementById("textbox1").value;
  var second = document.getElementById("textbox2").value;
  var answer = parseFloat(first) + parseFloat(second);

  var textbox3 = document.getElementById('textbox3');
  textbox3.value = answer;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="textbox1" id="textbox1" /> + <input type="text" name="textbox2" id="textbox2" />
<input type="submit" name="button" id="button1" onclick="myfunction()" value="=" />
<br/> Your answer is:--
<input type="text" name="textbox3" id="textbox3" readonly="true" />
```

Answer (score 2):

You're on the right track with using `document.getElementById()` as you have done for your first two text boxes. Use something like `document.getElementById("textbox3")` to retrieve the element. Then you can just set its value property: `document.getElementById("textbox3").value = answer;`

For the "Your answer is: --", I'd recommend wrapping the "--" in a `<span/>` (e.g. `<span id="answerDisplay">--</span>`). Then use `document.getElementById("answerDisplay").textContent = answer;` to display it.

Answer (score 0):

Even if this is already answered (1 year ago) you could also let the fields be calculated automatically.

**The HTML**

```
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" value="" ></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="class_name" placeholder="bla bla"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" value="" ></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="class_name" placeholder="bla bla."/></td>
    </tr>
```

**The script**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
                $(".class_name").each(function(){
                    $(this).keyup(function(){
                        calculateSum()
                        ;})
                    ;})
                ;}
                );
            function calculateSum(){
                var sum=0;
                $(".class_name").each(function(){
                    if(!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length!=0){
                        sum+=parseFloat(this.value);
                    }
                    else if(isNaN(this.value)) {
                        alert("Maybe an alert if they type , instead of .");
                    }
                }
                );
                $("#sum").html(sum.toFixed(2));
                }
```